# Awk Replace Header of a Text File

Tags: replace, awk

I need to fix the header of a text file.

Format:

```
Key firstRowColumn1 lastRowColumn1
1 Data
2 Data
3 Data
4 Data
```

Basically, the header has to have the first and last index, which is in the first column of my actual data.  I have a set of files that look like this:

```
Key 0 0
1 Data
2 Data
3 Data
4 Data
```

How can I use awk to fix them to look like the following?

```
Key 1 4
1 Data
2 Data
3 Data
4 Data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example use this:

```
$ awk 'NR==2 && FNR==2 {first=$1} NR>2 && FNR==1 {print "Key", first, prev; f=1; next} f{print} {prev=$1}' file file
Key 1 4
1 Data
2 Data
3 Data
4 Data
```

#### Explanation

It loops twice through the file. First time to fetch the data, then to print it.

- `NR==2 && FNR==2 {first=$1}` in the first loop, get the value of the 1st field on the 2nd line. This is the "first" value.
- `NR>2 && FNR==1 {print "Key", first, prev; f=1; next}` in case we are reading the file for the second time, print the header with the information gathered. Set the flag `f` as true, so that the lines will be printed from now on. Skip the record so that the current line is not printed.
- `f{print}` in case the flag `f` is set, print the line. This will be done during the second read of the file.
- `{prev=$1}` store the value of the first field, to be used in the next line to get the "end" value.

In case you want to update the current file, do:

```
awk '...' file file > new_file && mv new_file file
```

Comment: Hmmm, for whatever reason, that command seems to execute, but it doesn't print anything out for me.

Comment: @csnate strange... Nothing at all? What if you for example use `{first=$1; print first}` instead of just `{first=$1}`. Does it print anything?

Comment: It finds the first and last index perfectly.  Its just not printing the updated file.

Comment: @csnate it looks like `f{print}` is not behaving. Maybe you can replace it to `{if (f==1) print}`.

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: @csnate mmmm weird. Don't you even get the `Key 1 4` printed? You can debug it by using `awk '{print $0, NR, FNR}' file file` and see the `NR` and `FNR` at any moment. `NR` is the general counter, while `FNR` is the specific for each file. Don't know what else to say, as it works fine to me on `mawk 1.3.3`.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong.  I didn't realize you were supplying the file twice.  Thanks!

Comment: @csnate aaaah now everything makes sense : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "Key $(sed -n '2s/^\([^ ]\+\) .*/\1/p' yourfile) $(tac yourfile | sed -n '1s/^\([^ ]\+\) .*/\1/p')" && sed -n '2,$p' yourfile
```